# Master Z-Depth with multiple render layers

Tags: rendering

I was wondering if there is a way to output a Z-Depth pass for my entire scene which contains multiple render layers rather than a Z-depth pass for individual render layers? I have attached a screen shot of my compositing node tree and render. Thank you.
[image: Main Render]

[image: Node Tree]

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Z combine** node to compose Z channels into one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Crantisz! Will normalize work for animated frames?

Comment: This is usual node like the overs.

Comment: Aaah. So could I replace all my alpha over nodes with the Z combine nodes and output the Z-depth at the point I would like?

Comment: @R.Mayne of course